# Symfony One-To-Many unidirectional relation without JOIN table

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-mapping

I have the following tables:

```
strings
------
"id" int not null primary key

string_texts
------
"id"          int not null primary key
"string_id"   int not null fk(strings.id)
"language_id" int not null fk(languages.id)
"text"        text

"countries"
------
"id"      int not null primary key,
"name_id" int not null fk(strings.id)
```

All localizable text stored in a single table, and every other table connected to that table.

What I dont know is how to write the Country model? This is how I got so far.

```
namespace LoginHood\HoodBundle\Entity\Geo;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="StringText", mappedBy="")
     */
    protected $names;

    /*
    ...
    */


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->names = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Because of the structure you can't get the Country or any Entity from the StringText entity. But I don't want to make a join table, because its kind of an overkill, and totally meaningless.

Comment: Why is it overkill / meaningless?

Comment: You want to connect the **Companies** table with which table?

Comment: You can see my answer. May be the answer can give you some enlightenment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel, you have to use the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) / [Translatable behavior](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md) that will do the whole job for you:

- Deal with model modifications, almost like what you are doing
- Get directly the string in the correct language, when getting it
- ...

Comment: These strings have to be editable in the admin panel, this is why these are in database. And of course its an old project and I don't have time for any refactoring or something.

Answer (score -1):

I want to explain to you something you should know.

> Let's say that we have `table A`, `table B`, and `table C`.

and then

> you want the `table A`, `table B`, and `table C` having **relation** without **JOIN**

I will tell you that it is **imposible.**

**WHY ?**

> Actually, if  `table A`, `table B`, and `table C` have a **Relation**, 
>   it means that you are doing **JOIN** on your table.